# monetdb with web.py (raise UnknownDB, dbn issue)

Tags: python, web.py, monetdb

I tried using web.py framework to the monetdb.

This is my implementation code :

```
import web

render = web.template.render('templates/')
db       = web.database(dbn = 'monetdbd', user = 'monetdb', pw = 'monetdb', db = 'test')

urls = (
    '/','index'
)


class index:
    def GET(self,name):
        xSelect = db.select(x)
        return render.index(xSelect)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls,globals())
    app.run()
```

I have got the following error message while running python code.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 4, in <module>
    db       = web.database(dbn = 'monetdbd', user = 'monetdb', pw = 'monetdb', db = 'test')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/web.py-0.37-py2.7.egg/web/db.py", line 1145, in database
    raise UnknownDB, dbn
web.db.UnknownDB: monetdbd
```

The database server is running:

```
bmartis@bmartis-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Monetdb/web$ ps ucx| grep -i monetdb
bmartis   2482  0.0  0.0  63956  2476 ?        Ssl  Jun29   0:33 monetdbd
bmartis@bmartis-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/Monetdb/web$
```

I don't understand what is wrong with db definition here. What's the right syntax or monetdb doesn't have a support for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks likes web2py doesn't support MonetDB at this moment. You can find a full list of the supported databases and required drivers in the [Chapter 6](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer) of the [web2py Complete Reference Manual](http://web2py.com/book). As of today it looks like below:

- SQLite - `sqlite3` or `pysqlite2` or `zxJDBC` (on Jython)
- PostgreSQL - `psycopg2` or `pg8000` or `zxJDBC` (on Jython)
- MySQL - `pymysql` or `MySQLd`
- Oracle - `cx_Oracle`
- MSSQL - `pyodbc`  or `pypyodbc`
- FireBird - `kinterbasdb` or `fdb` or `pyodbc`
- DB2 - `pyodbc`
- Informix - `informixdb`
- Ingres - `ingresdbi`
- Cubrid - `cubriddb`
- Sybase - `Sybase`
- Teradata - `pyodbc`
- SAPDB - `sapdb`
- MongoDB - `pymongo`
- IMAP - `imaplib`